# How is the batch size been decided?

Tags: apex, batch

I have a Batch job with limit 20000 records in the Start method. 
And while executing I have put batch size to 900,

according to the documentation i should get Total No Records/Batch size 
this will result to 22.2 and making it to round off to 23.
But in my case I am getting 30,32,27 batchs processed in total.

[image]

Comment: Can you share screenshot of execution flow and your batch start block.

Comment: I have added the image

Comment: As I can see last 3 counts are 30. Are you sure you are getting 30,32,27. Share the start block code as well.

Comment: that was the latest. so its 30 30 and 27. it varies a lot. 
Assume it as a simple query like `select id,name from account limit 20000`

Comment: Is there any other user creating/deleting data in the background?

Comment: No its single user process. no body is creating any records while batch is running.

Comment: @arvind could you please share you batch apex code here?

Comment: Assume it as a simple query like `select id,name from account limit 20000`

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom batch size  (up to 2000 records) by providing a `QueryOptions` header. But if a SOQL statement selects two or more fields of type long text, the batch size will never be more than 200 records.

So I think in above case it takes 200 as batch size and total batch executed (30+30+30+10)

Comment: No the external system is calculated in such a way that it'll accept only 23 batch records. where as in our case its 30.

Comment: I thought your case was external one.